# Initialize a non injected angular service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a angular service that in its constructor listens to an event on the $rootscope.

This service is not injected anywhere in the application and therefore it is not initialized.
To solve that we're just injecting it and not using it in another service, just to get it to be "newd up".

Is there some way to initialize a service without having to inject it in some other service/controller/directive?

Comment: Use `module.run()` for initializations; if you want to encapsulate the logic in a service, have `run()` depend on that service and invoke an `init()` function (or just use the constructor as you did).

Comment: Thank you! Worked fine! If you put it in an answer I can accept it! I did not quite understand how I would make  `run()` dependent on my service. I just gave it a function pointer that had a `$inject` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, Angular gives you the `module.run(fn)` API to do initializations. The `fn` argument is fully injectable, so if you have a service, e.g. `myService`, that exposes an `init()` method, you can initialize it as:

```
angular.module(...).run(['myService', function(myService) {
    myService.init();
}]);
```

If the service initialization code is placed in the service constructor, i.e.:

```
angular.module(...).service(function() {
    ...initialization code...
});
```

...then it is enough to just declare the dependency on the service in your `run()` method, i.e.:

```
angular.module(...).run(['myService', function() {
    // nothing else needed; the `myService` constructor, containing the
    // initialization code, will already have run at this point
}]);
```

In fact, you can abbreviate it as below:

```
angular.module(...).run(['myService', angular.noop]);
```

---

(Sidenote: I find this pattern a bit awkward; if a service contains only initialization code, just implement the initialization code directly in a `run()` function. You can attach mulitple `run()` functions to each module anyway.)

Comment: Alright, I will just provide the initialization-function. There is no longer a need for it to be a service i guess.